# Angularjs same template and controller on different urls

Tags: route-provider

I have an application which can run into two contexts -- 1) Global and 2) Client

When in global context the urls are like this mydomain.com/#login, mydomain.com/#register but when in client context the urls are like this mydomain.com/#/ClientKey/login and mydomain.com/#/ClientKey/register. In both contexts I want to open exactly the same template i.e login.html and register.html. One way to achieve this is to replicate routeProvider.when for both cases like the following

```
 $routeProvider.when('/:ClientKey/_login', { 
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl', 
            })

 $routeProvider.when('/_login', { 
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl', 
            })
```

My question is that is there is way to do it in a single routeProvider.when, instead of replicating it twice with only a small difference. This is important for my application because there are several  such links like login, register, editProfile, changePassword etc.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var routes = {
    '/_login' : { templateUrl: 'views/login.html', controller:'LoginCtrl' }
    ...
}

for (var k in routes) {
    $routeProvider
        .when(k, routes[k])
        .when('/:clientId' + k, routes[k]);
}
```

Edit:

You can actually do optional groups with `?`, so the following might work.

```
$routeProvider.when(':clientId?/_login', { ... });
```

Comment: yes, its better, but does angular provide something like

        .when(k | '/:clientId' + k, routes[k])

Comment: @ShamailaTahir, angular don't allow us to specify multiple paths with OR operator(| / ||). Optional groups using <code>?</code> is a good solution for your problem.